# Выборка данных с группировкой по дате

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  department varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE history (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  employee_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  startJob datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  endJob datetime(0),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Две таблицы, связь один ко многим. Как выбрать присутствующих сотрудников, за день. Т.е. условие такое, startJob = '2017-02-22' -выбрать всех у кого startJob  попадает в этот период дня.

```
SELECT * from employees e 
INNER JOIN history h ON e.id = h.employee_id 
WHERE h.startJob >= ? AND h.endJob < ?
```

пытался сделать так, но если endJob еще не заполнен, мы не получим его в ответе.

Comment: используйте `ifnull()` или `coalesce()`

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, согласен с комментарием насчет coalesce:

```
    select * 
      from employees e 
inner join history h 
        on h.employee_id = e.id 
     where '2017-02-22' between h.startJob and coalesce(h.endJob, '2017-02-22');
```